# Handling multiple client requests with a single terminal interface

Tags: python, sockets, networking, concurrency, client-server

So I made a server script, and a client script and now I (server script) want to respond to multiple client scripts with a single terminal interface on which my server script is running. How do I do that, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) provides 2 ways using built in to create a TCP server which can handle multiple clients concurrently.  Both ways have source code [available](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socketserver.py#L624) too

In addition to a threading/multiprocess based approach you could use an [event loop approach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to handle multiple clients concurrently, using a single thread and process